# Changes In Image Data Not Reflected In ModelView

Tags: javascript, jsp, caching, servlets

in which i have to create a simple image editor to perform operations like flip, flop, adding border etc. Am using jsp servlets. Whenever an operation is performed a *POST* ajax request is sent to the server with data - image server relative path and the name of the operation. Am using ImageMagick to perform the operations - for quality issues . Once the changes are done (till then using ajaxloader) response is sent back to the view. Everything works fine until the user clicks on the operation as soon as one operation completes. The old image -with previous image editing operation is displayed again and after sometime the changes are reflected. I googled it and came to the conclusion that it is due to caching. I tried all possible things -

1. appended the path of server relative path of the image with a time stamp

   ```
   http://172.16.3.72:8080/~user/dataDir/workspace/2/tempData/ResizeImage.jpeg?random=1381852940376
   ```
2. appended the url of the ajax with a time stamp

   ```
   http://172.16.3.72:8080/cdl/captureImage.htm?pageNumber=2&isbn=AndItWorksFinally2?random=.332223223
   ```
3. used cache: false in jquery
4. Used header to disable cache

   ```
   response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
   response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
   response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
   ```

but all these things didn't help. Is there something else and not the cache issue? 
was wondering how facebook loads the images from the server so fast(no duplicates), when we click on the next button while viewing pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");`
`response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");`
`response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);`

instead of using this from jquery try to pass the header on the requested page itself.

and try to use unique image name on the requested page. usually browser show previously rendered images from cache.

Comment: It worked sir! Now every time am giving a unique name to the image which is being sent as a response from the server- appending time stamp to the name of the image!  Thanks a lot!